# python 3.x speech module

Tags: python, windows, speech

Is there pyTTS or some kind of speech module for python 3.0? I can't seem to find it anywhere and I'd really like to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

On windows, simplest way would be to directly access [SAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_API) using [python com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20213/) interface, e.g.

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")
```

Comment: I have tried this already but it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's because I'm running 64bit Win 7? (I have installed win32com but I can't import it)

Comment: hmm not sure abt 64bit Win 7, may be that is another question for SO

Comment: So looks like that I didn't have Microsoft speech sdk installed, but even now when I do have that installed I still can't import it. 
I read that I have to run makepy (tools | COM makepy utility | ... ) or something to make this work, but I don't seem to find it. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: This is when I try to import win32com.client (import win32com.client)

Comment: May be you said ask a separate question regarding problems with win32com

Answer (score 0):

Festival is the only TTS engine for Linux I know of, and it has pyfestival - http://code.google.com/p/pyfestival/ .

In the past I wrote my own bindings because the interface was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using win7 x64.
I installed pywin32 and Anurag Uniyal's answer worked.

Here is the latest build at the time of this writing.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/

You see there are 2 versions:
pywin32-218.win32-py3.1.exe
pywin32-218.win-amd64-py3.1.exe

Keep in mind that even if your OS is 64b, you might have installed python3 32b or python3 64b.
For example, I have win7 x64 but I installed python3 32b. If that's your case, choose win32; if not chose amd64.

Good luck