# Text to Speech Library for Python using Windows 8.1 (SAPI)

Tags: python, text, speech

I'm trying to create a simple program that will relay what I type as synthesized speech.  I've tried pyttsx, it has been known to not work with python 3.x and it sure doesn't. I also tried using speech, but it interfered with the speech_recognition Library I'm using.  I don't have any code to show since I don't even have a Library for it yet.

Running Python 3.4.2 32-bit on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275663/python-3-x-speech-module), considering that you are targeting the Windows platform, the following will work:

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")
```

Comment: just tried it, gave me an error ImportError: No module named 'win32api'

Comment: @Maskot Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257274/python-3-4-importerror-no-module-named-win32api

Comment: I installed pywin32, still nothing?

Comment: @Maskot That's odd. Try and restart your python interpreter, etc. and see if that does not work.

Comment: I got it to work, but now a new problem has surfaced

Comment: @Maskot If it's another problem, then you might need to ask another question. If this answered your first question, please mark it as answered, then ask your other question.